# how to download users twitter images from API with php

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-oauth

i am trying to download twitter users images that sign up in my website such that i can save them in my file to insert into my database later on for use in my website.

this is my TWITTER API:

```
 $user_pic = $user_info->profile_image_url_https;
```

i tried this and it works but i want it to download the image to my base file which is profilePictures/:

```
$twitterimage = file_get_contents($user_pic);
    $fp = fopen('path_to_filename.png', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $twitterimage); 
    fclose($fp);
```

now it is being downloading but  how can i download the twitter images and save them in my base file "profilePictures/"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution, all i had to do is this

```
$user_pic= str_replace('_normal','',$user_pic);
    $Imgurl = $user_pic;
    $target_path = "profilePictures/";
    $filename = basename($Imgurl);
    $saveLoc = $target_path . $filename;
    file_put_contents($saveLoc, file_get_contents($Imgurl));
```

and then save the `$saveLoc` variable into my database